# Is there some efficient algorithm to merge k sorted arrays in O(1) extra space or minimal extra space

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, bigdata, mergesort

Say i have K arrays A1 to AK of length L . I want to merge these array in memory without using much auxiliary space so that i have the final output of the form **smallest L elements are present in A1 next L smallest in A2 and so on** . Min priority queue based algorithm requires extra `L*K` space for output array. `L*K` is around 1 billion

Comment: You have K arrays of length L; what is N?

Answer (score 2):

You can merge k sorted arrays totalling length n, in-place, in O(n log k) time and O(1) auxiliary space. The time complexity is equal to the out-of-place solution using a heap.

The algorithm is described in the article [*Multiway in-place merging*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82410830.pdf) by Geffert and Gajdoš (2010):

> We present an algorithm for asymptotically efficient k-way merging. Given an array A containing k sorted subsequences A_1, ..., A_k of respective lengths n_1, ..., n_k, where Σ n_i = n, our algorithm merges A_1, ..., A_k into a single sorted sequence in-place and in
>   linear time, performing c_k·n + o(n) element comparisons and 3·n + o(n) element moves, where c_k = ⌊lg k⌋ + 2⋅(1 − 2⌊lg k⌋/k), which is a constant satisfying lg k ≤ c_k ≤ ⌈lg k⌉ and, moreover, bounded by c_k ≤ lg k + 0.0861. The algorithm does not merge stably, however, it does not require that the elements in A are all distinct.